# How to handle Firebase auth errors on Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I created a simple password login in my Unity app following the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth) and it works fine, however I would like to handle the different kind of errors and since `task.Exception` doesn't return an error code I don't know how to proceed.

I found [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error) but it doesn't seems to be the same Firebase version since the login method is different...

Comment: It seems like you are referring to legacy docs. Firebase is now part of google & new docs are available at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: I did followed the new doc but I don't find anything related to error handling in Unity: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth There is something equivalent for ios but not for unity (ios: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors ) Did I missed something?

Comment: That is correct, only thing that is exposed is task.Exception and it contains list of exceptions causing the issue but its really messy. Firebase did some changes in 4.0.3 sdk related to tasks dll file. I haven't checked it but u might wanna have a look.

Comment: So there is no way to get the FirebaseException original error except from the messy message from task.Exception, ok :/ Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Why do't you raise support request to firebase or to thr github page. They are very responsive at both places & get us the answer here too.

Comment: I asked this on the Firebase documentation page, but the Github is also a good idea thanks

Comment: @J'hacklelezard did you get any followup on those pages? can you post the links? I'm also looking for an error code as I need to do localisation and doing a switch on the error message feels terrible! :)

Comment: @geo I didn't get any answer on that subjet (that's why the issue is still opened), for now I handle the error by searching for known string like this: errorMsg.IndexOf("password is invalid") and when detected display my own message. Quite dirty but at least it works :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase has a AuthError enum that tells you the meaning of each ErrorCode in the FirebaseException, the documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/auth

To get the error message in Spanish I am doing this:

```
public static string GetErrorMessage(Exception exception)
{
    Debug.Log(exception.ToString());
    Firebase.FirebaseException firebaseEx = exception as Firebase.FirebaseException;
    if (firebaseEx != null)
    {
        var errorCode = (AuthError)firebaseEx.ErrorCode;
        return GetErrorMessage(errorCode);
    }

    return exception.ToString();
}

private static string GetErrorMessage(AuthError errorCode)
{
    var message = "";
    switch (errorCode)
    {
        case AuthError.AccountExistsWithDifferentCredentials:
            message = "Ya existe la cuenta con credenciales diferentes";
            break;
        case AuthError.MissingPassword:
            message = "Hace falta el Password";
            break;
        case AuthError.WeakPassword:
            message = "El password es debil";
            break;
        case AuthError.WrongPassword:
            message = "El password es Incorrecto";
            break;
        case AuthError.EmailAlreadyInUse:
            message = "Ya existe la cuenta con ese correo electrónico";
            break;
        case AuthError.InvalidEmail:
            message = "Correo electronico invalido";
            break;
        case AuthError.MissingEmail:
            message = "Hace falta el correo electrónico";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Ocurrió un error";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect this is the list I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a way to display only the error message using this:

```
FirebaseException error = task.Exception.InnerExceptions[0] as FirebaseException;
string errorMsg = error.ToString();
```

However it doesn't solve theoriginal problem, since it seems this is something missing in Firebase for Unity (at least for now).

Answer (score 0):

For me, you guys helped a lot, but I only got part of the way. I was looking to simply get the specific message from the Firebase.FirebaseException when for example an email was not valid or given - simply I wanted the response to go to the screen instead of only to the console.

This fixed it for me:

```
announcements.text = regTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].InnerException.Message;
```

This "regTask" is the register-user-task: "auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)".

Answer (score 0):

Actually newest Firebase api has a bit different exception structure. Now, to grab FirebaseException from AggregateException you need to use this:

```
public void HandleException(AggregateException exception)
    {
        Exception = exception;
        FirebaseException = exception.InnerExceptions[0].InnerException as FirebaseException;
        if (FirebaseException != null)
        {
            ErrorInReadableFormat = FirebaseException.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync (Email.text, Password.text).
ContinueWith (task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            //      
            ErrorText.text = "Error: " + task.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message;
            //
            return;
        }
});
```

I think this might be what you want.This will display "Error: " followed by what the message is and is really clean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the idea is to show a different log from the default Firebase one, in order for example to handle several langages. That's why I would have prefer a list of ID for each type of error instead of analysing the message string to detect the type of error and then display my own version to the user.

Comment: But maybe my question is rather a feature request and not a "bug"